# TextView color not affected by xml attribute android:textColor

Tags: android, textview

That is a weird issue, still can't find out why?
Setting up custom toolbar like below,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 ....>
    <include android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar" layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and textview in custom toolbar

```
<TextView
 .....
 android:text="@string/search_by_title_or_artist"
 android:textColor="@color/text_shadow_white"
 .... />
```

and style in theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    .....
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/material_gray_900</item>
    .....
</style>
```

final is BaseTheme

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

the issue is text color in custom toolbar is not overrided by `android:textColor`attribute no matter set any color. it is only be affected by `android:textColorPrimary` in theme style. but other texts not in custom toolbar like in list will be overrided by `android:textColor`.

Please tell me what wrong with that and how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First customize your `style.xml` like this :-**

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**then apply into your custom `toolbar`:-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

  <TextView
        .....
        android:text="@string/search_by_title_or_artist"
        android:textColor="@color/text_shadow_white"
        .... 
    />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: @Leon try this : android:textColor="#ffffff"

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!--<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>-->
    </style>

use this  Apptheme name in manifest.
@Leon

Comment: finally find the issue, that is my error which I have set text color in code. whatever accept this answer, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**try this it may help you.**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_transition"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: try and no luck

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="Search..."
              android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```